# CSS - Flip Card - contents appearing one over the other

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have designed flip cards. Actually the problem is that on **annual tab's** "**Show Details**" link is not working properly. So i couldn't show the hidden content. The jQuery code that i have written for showing the content is working properly. So when i click on the show details link, the contents are appearing one over the other. help me to fix this. Thanks in advance. **Note:** The above problem is occurring on mobile view.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("btn-active").css({
      "color": "#fff"
    });
    $(".flipreverse").removeClass("btn-active").css({
      "color": "#000",
      "transition": "0.5s ease-in-out"
    });
    $('.card').removeClass('flipped');
  })
  $(".flipreverse").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("btn-active").css({
      "color": "#fff"
    });

    $(".flip").removeClass("btn-active").css({
      "color": "#000",
      "transition": "0.5s ease-in-out"
    });
    $('.card').addClass('flipped');
  });

  $(".show-pricing-details, .hide-pricing-details").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Show Details") {
      $(this).text("Hide Details").removeClass("show-pricing-details").addClass("hide-pricing-details");
      $(this).parent().next().removeClass("hidden-xs hidden-sm").addClass("visible-xs visible-sm");
      return false;
    } else {
      $(this).text("Show Details").removeClass("hide-pricing-details").addClass("show-pricing-details");
      $(this).parent().next().removeClass("visible-xs visible-sm").addClass("hidden-xs hidden-sm");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 60px;
}

.boost-your-sales-bottom-wrap {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp button {
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp button:hover,
.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp button {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.bst-yr-sls-nav {
  border: 2px solid #555;
  border-radius: 50px;
  max-width: 448px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.btn-active {
  background: #1e6c97 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp button:first-child {
  margin-left: 6px;
  color: #fff;
}

.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp .navbar-btn:active,
.bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp .navbar-btn:focus {
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.flipcontainer {
  -webkit-perspective: 3500px;
  -o-perspective: 3500px;
  perspective: 3500px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.premium-card {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.premium-card>.front,
.premium-card>.back {
  border: 2px solid #ffcc29 !important;
}

.card>div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #555;
  position: relative;
}

.card .back {
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #555;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.flip-cards {
  margin-top: 40px;
  min-height: 2145px;
}

.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/css/pi-header-n-footer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default bst-yr-sls-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header bst-ur-sls-tgle-btn-wrp">
        <button class="btn navbar-btn btn-active btn-active flip">Monthly</button> <button class="btn navbar-btn flipreverse"><b>Annual</b> <small>Save ~ 35%</small></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row flip-cards">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mrgn-btm-20">
      <section class="flipcontainer flip-section1">
        <div class="card mrgn-btm-10">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Corporate</b></h3>
            <p>For Big Businesses</p>
            <h2 class="price"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;<b>1448</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <p class="mrgn-top-30 flex-lft-right-pad sm-mrgn-btm-20" style="margin-bottom: 120px;">Premium Access to Marketplace Features + Digital Marketing Campaign</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <p class="mrgn-btm-4">Not publicly available</p><button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Contact Us <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm"
                href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
                <p class="mrgn-btm-4">Not publicly available</p><button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2" type="button">Contact Us <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Corporate</b></h3>
            <p>For Big Businesses</p>
            <h2 class="price"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;<b>869</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <p class="mrgn-top-30 mrgn-btm-30 flex-lft-right-pad">Premium Access to Marketplace Features + Digital Marketing Campaign</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <p class="mrgn-btm-4">Not publicly available</p><button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Contact Us <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm"
                href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="flex-top-bdr pricing-tbl-bg">
                <div class="flex sales-details flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex">
                  <p class="mrgn-0"><b>Priority Support</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-top-10 mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on Skype</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on e-mail</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
                <p class="mrgn-btm-4">Not publicly available</p><button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2" type="button">Contact Us <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mrgn-btm-20">
      <section class="flipcontainer flip-section2">
        <div class="card premium-card">
          <div class="front pad-top-10">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Diamond</b></h3>
            <p>For Medium and Small Businesses</p>
            <h2 class="price mrgn-top-10"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;<b>82</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <p class="mrgn-top-30 flex-lft-right-pad" style="margin-bottom:44px;"><u>Full Access</u> to Marketplace Features</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <button class="btn btn-pi btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Phone Verification ($19 value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr pricing-tbl-bg">
                <div class="flex sales-details flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex">
                  <p class="mrgn-0"><b>Priority Support</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-top-10 mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on Skype</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times clr-red fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on e-mail</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr mrgn-btm-20">
                <button class="btn btn-pi btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Show Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back pad-top-10">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Diamond</b></h3>
            <p>For Medium and Small Businesses</p>
            <h2 class="price"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;<b>49</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <h4><span class="label label-default bg-ffcc29 clr-555">Save US$396 per year</span></h4>
            <p class="flex-lft-right-pad" style=""><u>Full Access</u> to Marketplace Features</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <button class="btn btn-pi btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Office Address Verification ($99/year value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Identity Verification ($39 value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Phone Verification ($19 value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr pricing-tbl-bg">
                <div class="flex sales-details flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex">
                  <p class="mrgn-0"><b>Priority Support</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-top-10 mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on Skype</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times clr-red fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on e-mail</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr mrgn-btm-20">
                <button class="btn btn-pi btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mrgn-btm-20">
      <section class="flipcontainer flip-section3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Pro</b></h3>
            <p>For Consultants</p>
            <h2 class="price"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;<b>65</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <p class="mrgn-top-30 flex-lft-right-pad"><u>Limited Access</u> to Marketplace Features</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Phone Verification ($19 value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr pricing-tbl-bg">
                <div class="flex sales-details flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex">
                  <p class="mrgn-0"><b>Priority Support</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-top-10 mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on Skype</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times clr-red fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on e-mail</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
                <button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3 class="clr-1E6C97"><b>Pro</b></h3>
            <p>For Consultants</p>
            <h2 class="price"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;<b>39</b></h2>
            <p class="text-center mrgn-btm-0">per month</p>
            <p class="mrgn-top-30 flex-lft-right-pad"><u>Limited Access</u> to Marketplace Features</p>
            <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
              <button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24 mrgn-btm-10" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button> <a class="link show-pricing-details visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Free Phone Verification ($19 value)</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr pricing-tbl-bg">
                <div class="flex sales-details flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex">
                  <p class="mrgn-0"><b>Priority Support</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-bdr flex-top-btm-pad">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-top-10 mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on Skype</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times clr-red fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-top-btm-pad mrgn-btm-20">
                <div class="flex flex-lft-right-pad boost-ur-sales-flex mrgn-btm-10">
                  <p class="text-left">Priority support on e-mail</p>
                  <p><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check clr-green fnt-22"></i></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="subsribe-btn-wrp flex-top-bdr">
                <button class="btn boost-btn btn-lg radius-2 mrgn-top-24" type="button">Get Started <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not going to downvote, but please read this: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/. It's really hard to go through all the code to figure out where's the issue. Plus, you don't have CSS included so I've had to make my own codepen, copy the code and then go to dev tools to inspect what is going on.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I have updated the code now. Please help me.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

The monthly side of your cards is controlling the height of the annual side of your card. So when you switch to the annual side it doesn't matter what Details you show or not, the height of the parent Card div will not change.

You need to do some further investigation and find a way to control the height of the parent div separately so that the height of the annual side is not linked to the monthly side.

If you go onto the monthly side and click Show Details on the second card, and then go to the annual side you will notice a large space after the second card.

[image: Annual Card for Diamond]

Sorry I can't be any more help, I hope you get there !

Comment: Thank you :). I have updated my code now. Can you please help me with that?